# Survival curve of Cox model

Tags: regression, cox-model

I am investigating factors associated with early discharge (vs full stay) in hospital amongst a cohort. Early discharge is the event. This is not an intervention study. I have 7 factors in the model, a mixture of categorical & continuous covariates. Is it appropriate to plot a Cox survival curve? Help & advice needed.

Comment: Note that there really is no Cox survival curve, the Cox model estimates hazard ratios and the survival curve itself needs to be estimated by other means.  Depending on your goals, the risk scores and coefficients from a Cox model might be enough.  What exactly are you trying to learn from your analysis?

Comment: I use SAS proc phreg with statements plots=survival & baseline survival=s, the results output has a 'survivor function for reference setting' graph & the reference values of covariates used to plot it; i therefore can overlay another curve using values i m interested in; the problem is i m not sure how meaningful it is to do this as continuous covariates for the reference curve are merely means of those covariates; my impression is it appears u can use it for estimating survival for individual pt as u already hv an equation, but to summarize/visualize the problem?

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.